# how to check if the string is overflowing from my view in android?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-imageview

I have a listview in Android which is dynamically loaded. The list view holds an image and on it is shows the description of the image which should ideally take up 20% of the images' height. How do I check if my textview which is on top of the image view in my list is taking a max height of 20% of the image?

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, "Harvey's - -check in for a chance to win a free burger
Picker, ON" is fitting in the textview in 2 lines, sometimes if my android device is small it exceeds the background (black colored) view and looks bad. I need to stop that so I decided I must truncate the string if it overflows on my textview.

How do I truncate the strings on the textview so that once that 20% of the imageview height has been reached the image description ends with "..."

The xml I have at the moment is given below. Note that com.parse.myPackage.AspectRatioImageView is just a custom view for an imageview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >

<com.parse.myPackage.AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/campaignImageLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/blank" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/fadedBlack">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/campaignNameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/campaignImageLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/fadedBlack">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaignLocationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Location Loading..."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You can use [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) to handle the truncation

Comment: can you add some code and screenshots?

Comment: @SList added screenshot and my XML, remove downvote maybe? and could you help me answer this question

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal - I didn't downvote you - I didn't want to see the question closed, because I also don't know the answer - but it's looking a lot better now - someone will be along to help in a minute I'm sure.

Comment: @SList, thanks ! Yeah I realize now that how badly I had originally posted the question. Appreciate the positive criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

If `android:maxLines="1"`does do your job then you can try `Android:singleLine="true"`